# Layout for site with three navbars

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to to work out how best to set my site up but have lost the last two days trying to solve an issue with content moving when I use jQuery validationEngine to validate forms.

The easiest way to explain what I'm trying to do is to show you what I want it to look like so [here'](https://jsfiddle.net/alofthedunnes/hwvo8z6k/5/)s a jsfiddle

The small navbar under the main one will contain the users relative position.

When I make the content div large it bleeds out the top when the user scrolls. I'm wondering how I set it up so that the content scrolls in behind the two bars and doesn't appear at the top. I can't figure out where the gap at the top is coming from to allow the bleeding.

Also, when I get that fixed. Will I be able to use jQuery validationEngine inside the content div without stuff jumping all around the place.

Stack is looking for code so

> test.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Tester</title>

    <style>
    body {
        padding: 0;  
    }
    .wrapper {
        margin:0 auto;
        width: 1000px;
    }
    .static {     
        width:1000px;
        z-index:2;
        height:120px;
        position: fixed;   
    }
    .header {
        background-color:Silver;
        height:100px;
    }

    .location {
        background-color:yellow;
        height:20px;
    }

    .content {
        background-color:Orange;
        width:800px;
        height:1500px;
        float: left;
        position:relative;
        top: 120px;
        scroll:hidden;
    }
    .menu {
        background-color:Green;
        position: relative;
        left: 800px;
        width:200px; 
    }

    </style>


    </head>
    <body>


    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="static">
            <div class="header">
                Header
            </div> 

            <div class="location">
               Location
            </div>

            <div class="menu">
                Menu
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Content
        </div>    

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I would add something like [normailze.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to your css files. Helps you reset all styles for all browsers. Should also make the unwanted gap on top of your header

Comment: Why am I getting down voted for my question? Is it worded badly?

Comment: Maybe someone thinks it's a too obvious question; that you're supposed to know this. I don't know.

Comment: Yes it is obvious. In my defence I don't use CSS much at all (I've been using Bootstrap when I need to do projects) so I've been struggling to get my base layout set without Bootstrap. It's been killing me the last few days. I used `normailze.css`and is working great. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `margin:0;`t o you body style.

```
body {
    padding: 0;  
    margin:0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this. My CSS isn't the best. Can I ask you if this is the best way to set things up? I was thinking of trying to make the content div fixed in size but internally scrollable - is this posssible and does it affect content inside it? Thanks again

Comment: it will not affect the content inside div.. You can do this also...and pls accept my answer if it helps you